# How can i have a control layer with buttons?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am new in javascript and leaflet. I have a leaflet map where there are two geotiff images, each image is represented in a layer with a checkbox and two buttons, one to go to the location of the image and other to delete the image and the layer.

Right now the code is:

header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <style>
        #map {
            height: 500px;
        }

        .custom-control {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            right: 10px;
            background-color: white;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 5px;
            z-index: 1000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Body:

```
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/georaster"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/georaster-layer-for-leaflet"></script>
    <script>
        var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 5);

        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);

        var geoTIFFLayerGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);

        function addGeoTIFFToGroup(imagePath, groupName) {
            fetch(imagePath)
                .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
                .then(arrayBuffer => parseGeoraster(arrayBuffer))
                .then(georaster => {
                    var layer = new GeoRasterLayer({
                        georaster: georaster,
                        opacity: 0.7,
                        resolution: 256
                    });
                    layer.addTo(geoTIFFLayerGroup);

                    var layerControl = L.control.layers(null, null, { collapsed: false }).addTo(map);

                    // Add a checkbox to the layer control for each GeoTIFF layer
                    layerControl.addOverlay(layer, groupName);

                    // Add the custom button to the layer control
                    var locationButton = L.DomUtil.create('button', 'custom-button');
                    locationButton.innerHTML = 'Go to Image Location';
                    locationButton.onclick = function () {
                        map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());

                    };
                    layerControl.getContainer().appendChild(locationButton);

                    // Add the custom button to the layer control
                    var deleteButton = L.DomUtil.create('button', 'custom-button');
                    deleteButton.innerHTML = 'Delete image';
                    deleteButton.onclick = function () {
                        if (layer) {
                            map.removeLayer(layer);
                            map.removeControl(layerControl);
                        }


                    };
                    layerControl.getContainer().appendChild(deleteButton);

                    map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
                })
                .catch(error => console.error('Error loading image:', error));
        }

        // Replace 'path/to/your/image.tif' with the actual paths of your local images

        var imagePath1 = 'Ortomosaico.tif';
        var imagePath2 = 'example_4326.tif';

        addGeoTIFFToGroup(imagePath1, 'GeoTIFF 1');
        addGeoTIFFToGroup(imagePath2, 'GeoTIFF 2');
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

It looks like:
[image: Original leaflet map]

As you can see each geotiff is in a layer control.

I want to group both layers so I can have a layer control with the two geotiff layer, each one with their buttons , text and checkbox.

I tried:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 5);

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    var geoTIFFLayerGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
    var layerControl = L.control.layers(null, null).addTo(map);

    function addGeoTIFFToGroup(imagePath, groupName) {
        fetch(imagePath)
            .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
            .then(arrayBuffer => parseGeoraster(arrayBuffer))
            .then(georaster => {
                var layer = new GeoRasterLayer({
                    georaster: georaster,
                    opacity: 0.7,
                    resolution: 256
                });
                layer.addTo(geoTIFFLayerGroup);


                // the custom button
                var locationButton = L.DomUtil.create('button', 'custom-button');
                locationButton.innerHTML = 'Go to Image Location';
                locationButton.onclick = function () {
                    map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
                };


                // the custom button
                var deleteButton = L.DomUtil.create('button', 'custom-button');
                deleteButton.innerHTML = 'Delete image';
                deleteButton.onclick = function () {
                    if (layer) {
                        map.removeLayer(layer);
                        map.removeControl(layerControl);
                    }
                };
                // add the buttons to the group
                geoTIFFLayerGroup.appendChild(locationButton); // error TypeError: geoTIFFLayerGroup.appendChild is not a function
                geoTIFFLayerGroup.appendChild(deleteButton); // error TypeError: geoTIFFLayerGroup.appendChild is not a function

                // add the group to the layer control
                layerControl.addOverlay(geoTIFFLayerGroup, groupName);
                map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error loading image:', error));
    }

    var imagePath1 = 'Ortomosaico.tif';
    var imagePath2 = 'example_4326.tif';

    addGeoTIFFToGroup(imagePath1, 'GeoTIFF 1');
    addGeoTIFFToGroup(imagePath2, 'GeoTIFF 2');
```

I thought if i do a group with the buttons and the Georaster layer, I can add it to the same layer control. But i have this error:

> error TypeError: geoTIFFLayerGroup.appendChild is not a function

I want to have a layer control so i have this button:
[image: layer control button]

When I position the mouse over the button, the button will show:
[image: wanted result]

How can i do it?

Another try i did was:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 5);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var geoTIFFLayerGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
var layerControl = L.control.layers(null, null).addTo(map);

function addGeoTIFFToGroup(imagePath, groupName) {
    fetch(imagePath)
        .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
        .then(arrayBuffer => parseGeoraster(arrayBuffer))
        .then(georaster => {
            var layer = new GeoRasterLayer({
                georaster: georaster,
                opacity: 0.7,
                resolution: 256
            });
            layer.addTo(geoTIFFLayerGroup);

            // Add a checkbox to the layer control for each GeoTIFF layer
            layerControl.addOverlay(layer, groupName);

            // Add the custom button to the layer control
            var locationButton = L.DomUtil.create('button', 'custom-button');
            locationButton.innerHTML = 'Go to Image Location';
            locationButton.onclick = function () {
                map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
            };
            layerControl.getContainer().appendChild(locationButton);

            // Add the custom button to the layer control
            var deleteButton = L.DomUtil.create('button', 'custom-button');
            deleteButton.innerHTML = 'Delete image';
            deleteButton.onclick = function () {
                if (layer) {
                    map.removeLayer(layer);
                    map.removeControl(layerControl);
                }
            };
            layerControl.getContainer().appendChild(deleteButton);

            map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error loading image:', error));
}

// Replace 'path/to/your/image.tif' with the actual paths of your local images

var imagePath1 = 'Ortomosaico.tif';
var imagePath2 = 'example_4326.tif';

addGeoTIFFToGroup(imagePath1, 'GeoTIFF 1');
addGeoTIFFToGroup(imagePath2, 'GeoTIFF 2');
```

And it looks like:

[image: bad result]

I want to have the buttons at the same level as their geotiff names and checkboxes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Carete a custom control for each layer to organize you GeoTIFF layers with buttons. Add a layer to the map,in the layer control’s DOM locate its corresponding item and insert your buttons.

```
layerControl.addOverlay(layer, groupName);
var listItem = layerControl._overlaysList.querySelector('label:contains("' + groupName + '")').parentNode;
var locationButton = L.DomUtil.create('button', 'custom-button', listItem);
locationButton.innerHTML = 'Go to Image Location';
// Similar for the delete button
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! I see the layer control but without the buttons. Maybe I did something wrong.
In my function `addGeoTIFFToGroup` I put your code and i don't see the button. What I did wrong? Thanks in advance